# Definition of factor - Is n a factor of n?

Tags: terminology, factoring

Is there a universally agreed upon definition of what a factor of a number is?

Is $n$ a factor of $n$?

Is $1$ a factor of $n$?

**EDIT x 2**: <del>Integers</del> Natural Numbers

Comment: Short answer: yes and yes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is meaningless to talk about factors without agreeing in advance what "numbers" we are using.  For example, $3$ is not a factor of $5$ if we use integers, but it *is* a factor of $5$ if we use fractions, because $3\cdot \frac{5}{3}=5$.

With this understanding, we say that

> $a$ is a factor of $b$ if there is another "number" $c$ (of the agreed-upon type), such that $ac=b$.

Because $1\cdot n=n$, both $1$ and $n$ are factors of $n$ (so long as our agreed-upon numbers contain $1$).

Comment: Perhaps also worth noting is that although you use integers as an example, they are usually not the agreed-upon "numbers" for determining whether one number divides another. Without further context, when asking for the factors of a natural number, most people will consider only natural numbers: you wouldn't expect to hear "six" as the answer to "how many factors does 4 have?", would you?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, $1$ and $n$ are, trivially, factors or [divisors](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor) of $n$.  In particular, if $n$ is a prime number, then the [prime factorization](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization#Prime_decomposition) of $n$ is simply $n$ itself.

That said, when speaking of the factors of a number, it is often useful to exclude these trivial factors.  The usual term for that is **"proper factor"** or "proper divisor".  Specifically, a proper divisor of a number $n$ is normally defined to be any divisor of $n$ which is strictly greater than $1$ and less than $n$.  In particular, this means that prime numbers do not have proper divisors, whereas all composite numbers do.